# Pass an object as OleVariant

Tags: delphi, interface, com

I have a class `TRate` descending from `IDispatch` and `TAutoObject`

```
Type
  IRate = interface(IDispatch)
  ['{60B5A5D1-5BA9-4D28-BBF9-DD5BE2B83ED2}']
  function Get_Minimum: Double; safecall;
  procedure Set_Minimum(Value: Double); safecall;
  function Get_Maximum: Double; safecall;
  procedure Set_Maximum(Value: Double); safecall;
  property Minimum: Double read Get_Minimum write Set_Minimum;
  property Maximum: Double read Get_Maximum write Set_Maximum;
end;

TRate = class(TAutoObject, IRate)
protected
  function Get_Maximum: Double; safecall;
  function Get_Minimum: Double; safecall;
  procedure Set_Maximum(Value: Double); safecall;
  procedure Set_Minimum(Value: Double); safecall;
public
  fMaximum,fMinimum:double;
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;


//INSIDE mscorlib_tlb.pas
// *********************************************************************//
// Interface :   IEnumerator
// Indicateurs : (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID :        {496B0ABF-CDEE-11D3-88E8-00902754C43A}  
// *********************************************************************//
IEnumerator = interface(IDispatch)
['{496B0ABF-CDEE-11D3-88E8-00902754C43A}']
  function MoveNext: WordBool; safecall;
  function Get_Current: OleVariant; safecall;
  procedure Reset; safecall;
  property Current: OleVariant read Get_Current;
end;

TRateEnum = class(TAutoObject, IEnumerator)
protected
  function Get_Current: OleVariant; safecall;
  function MoveNext: WordBool; safecall;
  procedure Reset; safecall;
public
  fAxe,fCount,fIndex:integer;
end;
```

I have next `g_Rate` an array of object of type `TRate`. I have to access to `g_Rate` members via `IEnumerator`. The standart function in `IEnumerator` is `Get_Current` and looks like that (returning an `OleVariant`):

```
Type
  g_Rate:Array [0..2,0..2] of TRate;
end

function TRateEnum.Get_Current: OleVariant;
begin
  result:= g_Rate[i,j];
end;
```

I get a compilation error, "type missmatch, Olevariant TRate", how can I avoid this problem?
Regards

Comment: Don't you need to cast the TRate to IRate. why didn't you show the declaration of g_Rate? A [mcve] would have helped. Knowledge of what sort of COM you are doing would likely have been useful.

Comment: Can you show us how you've declared TRateEnum? There's a pretty good example of how to define Enumerators here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416017/pass-an-object-as-olevariant

Comment: I have found a solution with th answer of David.`function TRateEnum.Get_Current: OleVariant;
begin
  result:= g_Rate[i,j] as IRate;
end;`, but I don't know why it's working. I am not very good with the use of Interfaces. I learn, I learn.

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing a COM method that returns a COM variant. The `OleVariant` type is used to represent a COM variant. From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.OleVariant):

> OleVariant is an OLE-compatible Variant. The main difference between Variant and OleVariant is that Variant can contain data types that only the current application knows what to do with. OleVariant can only contain data types defined as compatible with OLE Automation, which means that contained data types can be passed between programs or across the network without worrying about whether the other end will know how to handle the data.

You are trying to put a Delphi class into the `OleVariant`, and that is blocked because Delphi classes are not automation types. Instead you need to put an automation interface into the `OleVariant` that you return:

```
function TRateEnum.Get_Current: OleVariant;
begin 
  Result := g_Rate[i,j] as IRate; 
end;
```